# Can I use GIT LFS in the Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, git-lfs

I have 5 Gb file in the source code of Azure repo, I want to compress and use it.
How Can I integrate GIT LFS in the azure pipeline or how can I use this LFS tool in the azure devops?

[image]

Comment: Are you having a **specific** issue? What research have you done? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Git LFS is is fully supported and free in Azure DevOps Services. To use LFS with Visual Studio, you need at least Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. Just follow the instructions to install the client, set up LFS tracking for files on your local repo, and then push your changes to Azure Repos.

Fore more information, you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=azure-devops#use-git-large-file-storage-lfs).

Comment: Hi Ging Yuan, Thank you for the response, I know what I am going to ask might be basic question, I have run till here, my question since code is with 5 GB how below commands I have executed is going to help those large file in the code? I have pasted the screenshot in the first thread.